# Correct way to create a List(of Bytes) within a Class Structure

Tags: vb.net

I have the following Structure within a class:

```
Public Structure dataStruct
    Public dataPacket As List(Of Byte)
```

How do I efficiently use this list?

I have been trying things like:

```
    If rxDataStruct.dataPacket IsNot Nothing Then
        rxDataStruct.dataPacket.Clear()
    Else
        rxDataStruct.dataPacket = New List(Of Byte)
    End If
```

or

```
rxDataStruct.dataPacket = New List(Of Byte) From {0}
```

but each of these still gives me a 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' error when I try to call:

```
 rxDataStruct.dataPacket.Add(BytePacket)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize the `dataPacket` member when creating a `dataStruct` instance.

```
Dim value As New dataStruct()
value.dataPacket = new List(Of Byte)()
```

Note this would be much better if you used a `Class` instead of `Structure` here.  With a `Class` you can guarantee the `dataPacket` member is initialized for all instances by using a field initializer.

```
Public Class dataStruct 
  Public dataPacket As List(Of Byte) = New List(Of Byte)()
  ..
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks. I had a feeling the Structure isn't the right way to go, but it's part of a v-e-r-y big structure designed by someone else... and explaining that is more than I want to do today.